# knitr: how to get and override chunk options from inside a chunk

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have 2 questions about `knitr` chunk options:

**1)** Is it possible to override `knitr` chunk options from inside a chunk of code so that the options were applied in the same chunk? e.g. write something like the following lines and get result `as-is`:

````
```{r, results= "markup"}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(results= "asis")
    for (i in 1:5)
        print("# This text should be printed 'as-is'")
```
````

p.s. I'm familiar with `knitr::asis_output`.

**2)** Is it possible to get chunk options from inside a chunk? E.g., to use code like:

````
```{r}
   knitr::opts_chunk$get("results")
```
````

And get string `markup`.

````
```{r, results='asis'}
   knitr::opts_chunk$get("results")
```
````

And get string `asis`.

Unfortunately, `knitr::opts_chunk$get("results")` gets global options, and not the ones of a current chunk.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: Write a function, which resets `knitr` chunk option to `results='asis'` and prints several lines of text (`as-is`) and, say, several `trellis` and `plotly` objects as well.

Comment: Do you know this? http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/

Comment: You don't provide sufficient motivation for doing it within the **same** chunk. Give a real example of a case where this would be necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** Printings can be customized using functions `knitr::normal_print` and `knitr::asis_output` (as you mentionned). For instance :

````
```{r, results='markup'}
knitr::asis_output(replicate(5, "# This text should be printed 'as-is'\n"))

print("# This text should be printed 'normal'")
```
````

and alternatively

````
```{r, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:5)
    cat("# This text should be printed 'as-is'\n")

knitr::normal_print("# This text should be printed 'normal'\n")
```
````

**2)** Current chunk options can be retrieved using `knitr::opts_current$get()`. Use :

````
```{r, results='asis'}
knitr::opts_current$get("results")
```
````

and get string `asis`